# file_get_contents is blocked by website

Tags: php, json, curl

I use normally this Code to get JSON Content from API:

```
$url_price_mun = "https://coinsmarkets.com/apicoin.php";
$json_price_mun = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_price_mun), true);
print_r ($json_price_mun);
```

But in that case from this website `https://coinsmarkets.com/apicoin.php` I get an error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://coinsmarkets.com/apicoin.php):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service
>   Temporarily Unavailable

If I open this Website over a Browser than it's working. I've recognize that the website is cloudflare protected.

I've tested Curl with this code, too but the output was blank:

```
$url = 'https://coinsmarkets.com/apicoin.php';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
print_r ($obj);
```

I hope someone can help me to get the JSON Content from this website by PHP?

Comment: My guess would be that Cloudflare wait screen is giving you this problem. It checks browser, but I'm not sure how it behaves in terms of `curl` and similar

Answer (score 0):

It's a cloud flare protection. I don't know exactly how it works, but if you do any other call to this URL that is not a browser it's throwing Error 503. I also tried `wget` and `curl` in command line and have the same effect.